# Snippet showing double results

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-snippets

I'm facing a strange behavior with Stack Overflow's snippet option. Whenever I edit any post, and save a snippet, suddenly other posts' snippet are showing double results.

I don't know if this is only happening on my system or if it is a bug.

**POST 1**

---

> [image]

**Another Post**

---

> [image]

---

> I'm using Chrome and Windows 10.0.14393 (64 bit).